# Updated Rails to 4.2.1 and now it won't run

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have no idea what's going on.  I updated my rail to version 4.2.1 and now I can't generate a server.  I run

```
$rails s
```

like normal and it starts up fine but then immediately exits.  I've pasted the message below.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tzinfo1.2.2/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:182:in `rescue in create_default_data_source': No source of timezone data could be found. (TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound)
Please refer to http://tzinfo.github.io/datasourcenotfound for help resolving this error.
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tzinfo-1.2.2/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:179:in `create_default_data_source'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tzinfo-1.2.2/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:40:in `block in get'
    from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tzinfo-1.2.2/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:39:in `get'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tzinfo-1.2.2/lib/tzinfo/timezone.rb:629:in `data_source'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tzinfo-1.2.2/lib/tzinfo/timezone.rb:92:in `get'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tzinfo-1.2.2/lib/tzinfo/timezone_proxy.rb:67:in `real_timezone'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tzinfo-1.2.2/lib/tzinfo/timezone_proxy.rb:30:in `period_for_utc'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tzinfo-1.2.2/lib/tzinfo/timezone.rb:549:in `current_period'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:282:in `utc_offset'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:243:in `block in []'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:243:in `tap'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:243:in `[]'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb:61:in `find_zone!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/railtie.rb:20:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
    from C:/Users/Scott/CustomerDatabase/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Users/Scott/CustomerDatabase/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Scott/CustomerDatabase/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from C:/Users/Scott/CustomerDatabase/config.ru:in `new'
    from C:/Users/Scott/CustomerDatabase/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: add this to your gemfile `gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]`

Comment: Did you read the suggested link?

Comment: To be honest Frederick I was so frustrated I didn't even notice that link suggested in the code.  I actually just reverted to a previous version from my git.